# How to classify binary arm instruction during dis-assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I am writing a simple arm emulator. arm has different formats/Class of instruction as given on this [link](http://indepthdissection.comyr.com/1_13_ARM-Instructions-Set.html)
After reading instruction in binary format How can I determine to which class/format instruction belongs.

Comment: By looking at the bit patterns based on the table on the page you linked to (which comes from ARM's instruction set reference).

Comment: http://emucode.blogspot.se/2010/09/decoding-arm-instruction-set.html

Comment: Thanks @auselen it does give a starting point if you know any other links like this please post

Comment: Binutils arm dis-assembler code in [arm-dis.c](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=opcodes/arm-dis.c;hb=HEAD); the process of dis-assembly is fairly similar to the front-end of the emulator.  Instead of outputting text, you need to change state modelling the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently written a ARM emulator myself.

Here's the strategy I've used:

Use a mask and a value to test against after the mask has been applied.

Here's a snippet from the GNU disassembler for ARM:

```
  (* V7 instructions.  *)
  (arch:ARM_EXT_V7; value:$f910f000; mask:$ff70f000; i:_und; assembly:'pli'#9'%a'),
  (arch:ARM_EXT_V7; value:$f3af80f0; mask:$fffffff0; i:_und; assembly:'dbg'#9'#%0-3d'),
  (arch:ARM_EXT_V7; value:$f3bf8f50; mask:$fffffff0; i:_und; assembly:'dmb'#9'%U'),
  (arch:ARM_EXT_V7; value:$f3bf8f40; mask:$fffffff0; i:_und; assembly:'dsb'#9'%U'),
  (arch:ARM_EXT_V7; value:$f3bf8f60; mask:$fffffff0; i:_und; assembly:'isb'#9'%U'),
```

And here's how you apply it:

1. Read next instruction bytes.
2. Correct for big/little endian mode if needed.
3. `if (InstructionBytes and Mask) = value` then we have a match
4. Interpreted the remaining bits according to the instructions in the assembly string.
5. If ARM interpreted the condition code etc...

You need to make sure you apply the masks in the correct order.
Instructions introduced in a newer revision should always be checked first.

There is no need to worry whether you're in ARM or Thumb mode.
Just disassemble for both and store both disassemblies side by side. If a mode change occurs switch the table you're reading your disassembled instructions from.